# How to disable a form from scrolling up after clicking out of a textinput

Tags: react-native, scroll

What I basically have is a view with a form that has a bunch of text Inputs, sth like this:

```
 <View>
        <Form>
         <SectionHeader name="Date" align/> 
          <InputItem datePicker error={!!errors.startDate}>
            <TextField placeholder="initial Date"
                       onChangeText={(value) => {onFormChange('startDate', value)}}
                       value={form.startDate}
                       editable={false}
            />
          </InputItem>
.......
```

When I scroll down to fill lower text Inputs and then click outside the text input (which is basically a text field) the screen automatically scrolls up .

I have tried solutions on this one:
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/339

but nothing worked for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, I inserted this in my header component and it solved the issue:
disableKBDismissScroll={true}